# vsql with multiline recall

Tags: macos, readline, vertica, vsql

I'm on osx, and I installed vsql by following [this](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/vsql/Install/InstallingTheVsqlClient.htm).

When I input a multiline statement into vsql, then hit up, I only recall one line of the statement at a time. I would like to be able to recall and rerun multiline statements with the up arrow key.

Can someone offer assistance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible at all to do this, I think it would be using an `initrc`. I am not aware of a way, but the best I can tell you is to use `\g` to run a query a**g**ain and `\s` to **s**how the history.

Comment: I'm using a vsqlrc to get things like keybindings, but I haven't been able to figure out the multiline configuration

Comment: The only thing I could think of was maybe to somehow redefine what an EOL is and make it a semicolon. I really don't know if it can be done, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the \e metacommand to bring up the whole query in the shell default text editor.

Comment: This is great, and helps quite a bit. How did you find out about this query?

Comment: I notice when rerunning a multiline command with \e, the newlines are substituted with control sequence `^J`, like 
`select <newline>
1;`
turns into `select^J1;` when I recall it again. Maybe this is a hint to solving the problem?